# Question about using Group or Role in frontend application to restrict view

Tags: python, django, security, django-rest-framework, permissions

I am building an application that comprises a python backend using the django framework and a vue application on the frontend. I am using with success the authorization and permissions framework provided by django. I have created groups that possess a set of permissions and I have assigned users to them. Technically, after reading the docs, it is recommended to use groups to check for permissions and not roles. A problem arises when I need to serialize the user and send it to the frontend. What kind of information should I send to determine permissions on the frontend? Should I serialize all the groups the user belongs to with the respective permissions, or should I create a role field in my database to simplify things out (the roles are quite well defined) and just send that. What is the common solution or what would be reasonable? What kind of questions should be answered when approaching this problem? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I have been in similar situation and tried these 3 things.

1. Role Column in DB: This approach quite easy and simple implement. Give you enough control at frontend. But drawback is, you wouldn't utilize the power of groups in django. And groups are very useful when user have basket of permissions.
2. Use django Groups feature as role: Django inbuilt feature of group quite easy to maintain user permissions, also if needed multiple roles can also be implemented. Django admin module will be easy to configure your groups.
3. Use both Django Group and Role Column in DB: Don't do that, the code become messy, and it will be painful to keep track of two things without any additional benefit.

My suggestion go with 2nd approach.